# Putting a new value into a Map if not present, or adding it if it is

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `java.util.Map<Foo, Double>` for a key-type class `Foo`. Let's call the instance of the map `map`.

I want to add {`foo`, `f`} (`foo` is an instance of `Foo`, and `f` a `Double`) to that map. But if the key `foo` is already present I want to sum `f` to the current value in that map.

Currently I use

```
Double current = map.get(foo);
f += current == null ? 0.0 : current;
map.put(foo, f);
```

But is there a funky way of doing this in Java 8, such as using `Map#merge`, and `Double::sum`?

Regrettably I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

this is what the merge function on maps is for.

```
map.merge(foo, f, (f1, f2) -> f1 + f2)
```

this can be reduced even further to

```
map.merge(foo, f, Double::sum)
```

it is basically the equivalent of

```
if(map.contains(foo)){
    double x = map.get(foo);
    map.put(foo, x + f)
} else {
    map.put(foo, f)      
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
map.put(foo, f + map.getOrDefault(foo, 0d));
```

The *value* here will be the one that corresponds to `foo` if present in the `Map` or `0d`, otherwise.

Comment: It's a small thing, but that does do two lookups on the map. But I still vote this.

Comment: Where does the addition with `f` take place?

Comment: @AndréStannek, I hadn't had my breakfast this morning and I accidentally  ate the `f`. :)

Comment: Presumably f + map.getOrDefault(foo, 0d)