# Streaming a map to add a value

Tags: java, java-8

I have a working bit of code that looks a bit clunky to me.  I would like to make it a bit more functional programming style but I'm struggling.  I wondered if anyone could help (or maybe this is the best way ?) ?

```
private Map<String, Integer> container;

public void addItemToMap(String item, Integer quantity ){

        if(container.containsKey(item)){
            container.compute(item, (k,v ) -> Integer.valueOf(v+quantity));
        }else{
            container.put(item, quantity);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: okay have done.  I was going to leave it as it's been (correctly) marked as dupe.  But happy to agree that that is the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `if-else` with the following one liner:

```
container.compute(item,(k,v) -> v == null ? quantity : Integer.valueOf(v+quantity));
```

In the above eg. it is assumed that there are non-null values.

But, as mentioned by `Sotirios` in the comments, and also mentioned in the [Map.compute doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-), it is better to use [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) here, as follows([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021044/820410)) :

```
map.merge(item, quantity, Integer::sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just using that map as a counter?

I would suggest guava's Multiset: your function would be just a call to [Multiset#add()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#add(E,%20int)).